# Input stepping down

Tags: php, css

I'm having a step down issue with my registration form, I've tried everything I can find on google but nothing works.

My DOB section is split into 3 different input boxes, I'm trying to get the right column up beside the left but as soon as I put any styling on it, the year section steps down.

I've tried so many different variations; Float, display, nothing works. Also I've added extra boxes and it's always after the first 2 boxes the step down happens.

**When I try to style, notice the year step down:**

[image]

**Always steps down after 2 no matter what order:**

[image]

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="regforms">
    <form method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform" id="registerform">
        <fieldset2>
            <div id="regforms1">
                <label for="username"></label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username"/><br />
                <label for="password"></label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/><br />
                <label for="email"></label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/><br />
                <input type="submit" name="register" id="login" value="Register" />
            </div>
            <div id="regforms2">
                <label for="name"></label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"/><br />
                <div id="dob">
                    <label for="dobm"><input type="text" name="month" id="month" placeholder="MM"/><br />
                    <label for="dobd"><input type="text" name="day" id="day" placeholder="DD"/><br />
                    <label for="dobd"><input type="text" name="day" id="day" placeholder="DD"/><br />
                    <label for="dobd"><input type="text" name="day" id="day" placeholder="DD"/><br />
                    <label for="doby"><input type="text" name="year" id="year" placeholder="YYYY"/><br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset3>
    </form>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#regforms {
margin-top:200px;
border: 0; 
display:block;
width:600px;
}

#regforms1 {
padding-right:25px;
width:275px;
float:left;
}

#regforms2 {
width:275px;
float:right;
}

#dob {
}

#month{
width:5%;
margin-right:5px;
}

#day{
width:10%;
margin-right:5px;
}

#year{
width:10%;
margin-right:5px;
}
```

Comment: If i am getting your problem correctly then, you have need just reemoove <br /> tag..in your html code

Comment: Bloody hell, such a trivial thing has been doing my head in for days, how embarrassing.

Thanks!

Comment: PHP tag needs to be removed, HTML tag needs to take it's place. There is no Server sided problem here.

Answer (score 0):

As Aligarian said, you just need to remove the `<br/>` tag, although **you don't seem to be closing the `<label>` tags** in the DOB fields; you should close them.